# How does Angular know which "event" to bind to in Two-Way Data Binding

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I understand that in Angular the following two lines are functionally the same

**Property and Event binding**

```
<input type="text" [value]="customerName" (input)="customerName= $event.target.value" />
```

**Two-Way Data Binding**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="customerName' />
```

What confuses me is how Angular knows, with Two-Way Data Binding, to bind to the **input** `event` of the `input` elementy rather than any of the other events that the `input` element supports?

In the first example the code is specifically defining which event to bind to (the **"input"** `event`), but not in the second example. How does Angular choose the event to bind to?

Comment: Input directive uses `input` event by default - [docs](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/input/input.ts#L88)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<input [(ngModel)]="customerName">` is a short form of `<input [ngModel]="customerName" (ngModelChange)="customerName = $event">`. This is a convention in Angular and also works with your own custom defined directives.

The NgModelDirective (bound by [ngModel]) provides `@Input('ngModel') model: any;` and
`@Output('ngModelChange') update = new EventEmitter();`.

I can recommend to take a look here at the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) and also at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts) to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The two way data binding isn't really binding to the input event, it's the way the `ngModel` directive works: It passes any changes in the value of the given object to the input element and vice versa.